# Count the number of sql dataframe in spark by map function in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

A newbie in spark and have a problem about `map` function on data frame. I have a spark sql dataframe, named `df`, assuming it is like:

```
+----------+------------+------+
|      time|         tag| value|
+----------+------------+------+
|1399766400|A00000000001|1000.0|
|1399766401|A00000000002|1001.0|
+----------+------------+------+
```

I can select part of them based on the tag value with the command:

```
temp = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM df WHERE tag = 'A00000000001'")
temp.show(1)
```

then we have:

```
+----------+------------+------+
|      time|         tag| value|
+----------+------------+------+
|1399766400|A00000000001|1000.0|
+----------+------------+------+
```

Currently, I have a list

```
x = ["SELECT * FROM df WHERE tag = 'A00000000001'", "SELECT * FROM df WHERE tag = 'A00000000002'"]
```

which has been stored as RDD variable and I would like to apply `map` function on it to count the number of dataframe selected based on them, I tried the function like:

```
y = x.map(lambda x: sqlContext.sql(x).count())
y.take(2)
```

I supposed that the return value should be `[1, 1]`, but it gives the error:

```
TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

Is it possible to execute a map function on a dataframe with this method? if not, how should I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated it is not possible to execute nested operations on distributed data structures. In more general sense Spark is not a database. Spark data structures, including `DataFrames` are not designed for tasks like single record retrieval.

If all the queries follow the same pattern where you use simple filter by column it is only a matter of simple aggregation with and join:

```py
tags = sc.parallelize([("A00000000001", ), ("A00000000002", )]).toDF(["tag"])
tags.join(df, ["tag"]).groupBy("tag").count()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. You can use list comprehensions:

```
>>> xs = ["SELECT * FROM df WHERE tag = 'A00000000001'", "SELECT * FROM df WHERE tag = 'A00000000002'"]
>>> [sqlContext.sql(x).count() for x in xs]
```

Comment: So, if the list in rdd variable, then I have to `collect` then first? it will take a long time to `collect`.

Comment: Unless your RDD is bound by a "small" number of elements, it's recommended to avoid collecting as it brings all the data to master and it may "blow it" up giving an OME. I would definitely consider @zero323 answer as a cleaner solution.